# Hazelcast successfully discovers nodes but unable to connect (OrientDB)

Tags: amazon-ec2, orientdb, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast in EC2 discovery mode to allow OrientDB to run in distributed mode. The nodes are running in the same security group under the same EC2 role. The plugin successfully discovers other nodes but fails to connect over ports 5701-5703. Here is the error message:

*2019-05-31 19:44:45:303 INFO  [10.4.31.181]:5701 [orientdb] [3.8.4] Could not connect to: /10.4.26.235:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection timed out to address /10.4.26.235:5703] [InitConnectionTask]*

I checked if any process is listening on those ports on other nodes (lsof -i -P -n) and discovered these entries

```
java      10023    root   91u  IPv6 357165      0t0  TCP *:2424 (LISTEN)
java      10023    root   92u  IPv6 357166      0t0  TCP *:2480 (LISTEN)
java      10023    root  135u  IPv6 357826      0t0  TCP *:5701 (LISTEN)
```

It seems that all OrientDB listeners are using IPv6 although I never enabled it anywhere (there are no IPv4 listeners). How do I make it listen using IP4? Here is the only thing I changed in hazelcast.xml after I install it.

```
<network>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false"/>
            <aws enabled="true">
              <tag-key>Name</tag-key>
              <tag-value>orientdb-test</tag-value>
            </aws>
        </join>
</network>
```

Comment: make sure you have opened ports on nodes to listen to connections

Comment: You can also try adding the JVM option to prefer IP4 over IP6 (`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`). But as mentioned by @GaneshKarewad, the first thing I'd check is the security groups and open ports on EC2 Instances.

Comment: @GaneshKarewad they're in the same AWS security group so they should have no problems talking to each other

Comment: I am facing the same issue but I am trying to connect over TCP